# Jquery autocomplete causes select lists to be checked on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, html

When the jquery autocomplete choices menu comes up while typing in a name - it displays over a select list. On the ipad this hovering choice menu will cause click events on the select list it hovers over.

Any way to stop this?